# How to include input file name provided to a function in the resultant output column name

Tags: r, dplyr, purrr

I am new to use functions on lists.

I wrote a function to perform a statistical test over a set of values. I import the set of values as a list into the function as input and run the program. However I observed that the output file have similar output column names. Can we replace/include the input file name in output file column names ?

Here I am attaching a sample code.

```
library(nycflights13)
library(tidyverse)

## Sample data ##
FlightOriginDestination <- nycflights13::flights %>% 
  dplyr::select(flight, origin, dest) %>% 
  dplyr::distinct()

Dest <- FlightOriginDestination %>% 
  dplyr::select(dest) %>% 
  dplyr::distinct()

## Mulptiple input files ##
List1 <- Dest %>% 
  slice_sample(n = 5) %>% 
  dplyr::distinct()

List2 <- Dest %>% 
  slice_sample(n = 5) %>% 
  dplyr::distinct()

List3 <- Dest %>% 
  slice_sample(n = 5) %>% 
  dplyr::distinct()

## Combining the input files
Destination <- list(
  List1,
  List2,
  List3
)

## Function to perform a basic quantitative representation
Function1 <- function(Data){
  Data %>% 
  dplyr::left_join(FlightOriginDestination) %>% 
  dplyr::distinct() %>% 
  dplyr::count(flight, name = "Data")
}

## applying the function on the list
map(Destination, Function1) %>% 
  reduce(full_join, by = "flight") %>% 
  mutate_all(~replace(., is.na(.), 0))
```

Below is the header of output file. Can we replace/include Data.x, Data.y and Data with input file names (List 1, List2, List3).

```
## Output ##

Joining, by = "dest"
Joining, by = "dest"
Joining, by = "dest"
# A tibble: 1,396 x 4
flight Data.x Data.y  Data
<dbl>  <dbl>  <dbl> <dbl>
1      4      1      0     0
2      9      1      0     0
3     18      1      0     0
4     27      1      0     0
5     28      1      0     0
6     31      1      0     0
7     41      1      0     0
8     43      1      0     0
9     45      1      0     0
10     52      1      0     0
# ... with 1,386 more rows
```

I am newbie on stackoverflow. Kindly let me know if the presentation of question is complicated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I made Destination into a named list. Then use rename_with() in the function to rename all but the first column with the names from the named list

````
Destination <- list(
    List1 = List1,
    List2 = List2,
    List3 = List3
)

## Function to perform a basic quantitative representation
Function1 <- function(Data){
    Data %>% 
        dplyr::left_join(FlightOriginDestination) %>% 
        dplyr::distinct() %>% 
        dplyr::count(flight, name = "Data")
}

## applying the function on the list
map(Destination, Function1) %>% 
    reduce(full_join, by = "flight") %>% 
    mutate_all(~replace(., is.na(.), 0)) %>%
    rename_with(function(x) names(Destination), .cols = -1)
    ```

Output looks like this:
 flight List1 List2 List3
    <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>
 1      1     1     0     0
 2      5     1     0     0
 3      7     1     0     0
 4     10     1     0     0
 5     11     1     0     0
 6     12     1     0     0
 7     15     1     0     0
````

Comment: Was I able to answer your question? If so, could you mark as the acceptable answer?